# can I run a shell task in VSCode that uses a specific shell for a python virtualEnv?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I'm writing some python to render stuff that I tweak and run a lot, and that runs inside a virtual env. I would like a keyboard command to run a bash script (that launches python) inside the known terminal and virtual env.

I played a bit with setting up a shell script and a custom task, but entering the virtual env is always a bit tricky.

I don't need a debugger or anything complicated, just a way to run the python code and attach a keystroke to it.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py

Comment: "args": ["-c", "source myvenv/bin/activate; pip install -r requirements.txt"]     like this?

Comment: i think the trick below to just run the python inside the venv avoids all that? I already have a venv activated and dont want to reinstall each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can just run the `python.exe`/`python` binary in the virtualenv folder as an executable.

So to run a specific python file with a virtual environment:
For Windows it would be `.\path_to_virtualenv\Scripts\python.exe yourfile.py`, and for Unix system it would be `./path_to_virtualenv/bin/python yourfile.py`

And instead of running a python file, you can probably pipe the input command into the python executable in the path above if you want to run a specific python command.

So something like `COMMAND | ./path_to_virtualenv/bin/python yourfile.py`

Comment: OK thats great to know it's so easy to run in context of the venv like that. So now i only need to know how to turn that into a VSCode task!

Comment: Not sure how to go about setting the python venv path in the task, but I'd say you can have a shell script wrapped over it and use that shell script as a task instead.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please explain the difference between the way you want and the following operation:

1. Use "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select Interpreter" (the same as click the interpreter in the lower right corner which is on the right side of python).

[image]

2. Use "Run Python".

I think there is no difference because before your using a keyboard command, you still need to choose the interpreter.

By the way, use [jupyter notebook](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks) or [interactive window](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py) will be a good chioce as well.

Comment: no it's important this runs inside a specific venv

Comment: @dcsan I suggest you using interactive window.